# Virtual Directories in Linux

Tags: linux

Why the directories under ROOT (`/`), like `bin`, `boot`, `etc`, `home`, `root`, `var`,... called virtual directories? As they exist actually on the system?

Comment: They're not. Where did you hear that they are?

Comment: Oh. Perhaps you meant `/proc` and `/sys`?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: For this type of question, you will have to state by-whom. Give references.

Comment: I am really interested in where this comes from. Please edit, with references, then I will up-vote.

Answer (score 3):

They aren't.

`/proc` and `/sys` on the other hand could be called that, since the filesystems mounted on them don't have any backing storage, or a traditional filesystem data structure. Instead, their contents are just created on the fly from various kernel data structures. (`proc` has data on processes, along with the `sysctl` parameters, along other stuff; and `sys` has data on devices on the system.)

<sub>(The *directories* `/proc` and `/sys` still have to exist on the root filesystem so that something can be mounted on them. After mounting, you won't be able to see them, though.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I like the word *virtual*, so I looked up "Virtual Directory" in wikipedia:

> folder which appears in a path but which is not **actually** a
>   subfolder of the preceding folder in the path

Mostly it means an additional layer through a virtual directory server (VDS).

But if you consider the concept of mounting filesystems, and symlinks, your list really contains some special "folders".

`/bin` is only a *link* (to /usr/bin).

`/boot` contains whatever device you mount to it. Same for `home` and `var`.

Would be better to speak of (possible/default) mountpoints than "virtual directories".

Here I rather get `/dev`, `/run` and `/tmp` as special folders in "/", beside `/proc` and `/sys`:

```
]# findmnt |grep '^|-' 
|-/proc                               proc        proc        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
|-/sys                                sys         sysfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
|-/dev                                dev         devtmpfs    rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4023440k,nr_inodes=1005860,mode=755
|-/run                                run         tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755
|-/tmp                                tmpfs       tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev
```